# Reading a whole line before printing result

Tags: c, getchar

Ok firstly I'm a total amateur on programming and i wanted to try something. I want to make a C program which will read a line and then if the characters are accepted to print "ACCEPTED" or "REJECTED" if the characters are valid or not.

So I've used a while loop and some if-else if to add the viable characters. The viable characters are the letters of the alphabet ',' '.' '/' '[' ']'. The problem is that after i type the whole line, it prints ACCEPTED and REJECTED for every character on the line. How can i get the program to read the whole line first and then print the result?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char c;
    c=getchar();
    while(c!=EOF) {
        while (c!='\n') {
            if (c>='a' && c<='z') {
                printf("OK!\n");
            }
            else if(c==','|| c=='.' ||c=='/') {
                printf("OK!\n");
            }
            else if(c==']'||c=='[') {
                printf("OK!\n");
            }
            else {
                printf("ERROR!\n"); 
            }
            c=getchar();
        }
        c=getchar();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask] and [help] on how to ask a question.  Maybe showing your code?

Comment: Nice to hear that you wrote a program for that. Could you post that code to help us to answer your question?

Comment: The symptoms you're describing fit with having the `printf` statements inside the `for` loop inside of out of it.  As the other commenters mentioned, if you show us the code, we can answer your question directly.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, my original answer did not seem to relate to your question. Skim reading fail.

Thank you for posting the code, it helps a lot when it comes to answering your question correctly.

Ignoring style for now, I would change your code in this way to make it print `OK` only when you finish parsing the entire line and it is exactly what @ScottMermelstein said but with code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c; // This needs to be an int otherwise you won't recognize EOF correctly
    int is_ok;

    c=getchar();
    while(c!=EOF) {
        is_ok = 1; // Let's assume all characters will be correct for each line.
        while (c!='\n') { // So long as we are in this loop we are on a single line
            if (c>='a' && c<='z') {
                // Do nothing (leave for clarity for now)
            }
            else if(c==','|| c=='.' ||c=='/') {
                // Do nothing (leave for clarity for now)
            }
            else if(c==']'||c=='[') {
                // Do nothing (leave for clarity for now)
            }
            else {
            is_ok = 0; // Set is_ok to false and get out of the loop
                break;
            }
            c=getchar();
        }

        if (is_ok) // Only print our result after we finished processing the line.
        {
            printf("OK!\n");
        } else 
        {
            printf("ERROR!\n");
        }

        c=getchar();    
    }

    return 0; // If you declare main to return int, you should return an int...
}
```

However, I would recommend modularizing your code a little more. This will come with time and practice but you can write things in a way that is much easier to understand if you hide things away in appropriately named functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_valid_char(int c)
{
    return (isalpha(c) || c == ',' || c == '.' || c == '/' || c == '[' || c == ']');
}

int main(void) {
    int c;
    int is_valid_line;

    c=getchar();
    while(c!=EOF) {
        is_valid_line = 1;

        while (c!='\n') {
            if (!is_valid_char(c)) {
                is_valid_line = 0; // Set is_valid_line to false on first invalid char
                break;             // and get out of the loop
            }
            c=getchar();
        }

        if (is_valid_line) // Only print our result after we finished processing the line.
        {
            printf("OK!\n");
        } else 
        {
            printf("ERROR!\n");
        }

        c=getchar();    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice update. +1. See the OP's edit to the question (as expected) :) .

Comment: @haccks I see, well thanks anyway. I would have completely missed his question if you didn't correct me. And for the downvoter, a comment would have been appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scanf` and putting a space before the format specifier `%c` to ignore white-space.

```
char ch;
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

Comment: To read character by character the answer is fine. It does't deserve a downvote. +1. Note: You should mention about why it is printing `ACCEPTED` or `REJECTED` after each character (because of `\n`, of course).

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for?

Read a line and process good/bad chars and print either OK or Error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void  )
{
char buff[1000];
char *p = buff ;
char c ;
int  flgError= 0 ; // Assume no errors
gets( buff ) ;
printf("You entered '%s'\n", buff );
while ( *p  )  // use pointer to scan through each char of line entered
   {
   c=*p++ ;    // get char and point to next one
   if (  // Your OK conditions
        (c>='a' && c<='z')
        || (c>='A' && c<='Z')     // probably want upper case letter to be OK
        || (c==','|| c=='.' ||c=='/')
        || (c==']'||c=='[')
        || (c=='\n' )         // assume linefeed OK
        )
        {
        // nothing to do since these are OK
        }
    else
        {
printf ("bad char=%c\n",c);
        flgError = 1;  // 1 or more bad chars
        }
   }

if ( flgError )
   printf ( "Error\n" );
else
   printf ( "OK\n" );
}
```